# Pandas: Remove group rows where a particular value for that group is followed by another value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["A", "A","A", "A", "B" ,"B","B" ,"B", "C", "C","C", "C"],
                   "nickname":["X","Y","X","Z","X","Y","X","Y","Y", "X","Y", "Y"]})
```

How can I group df by "name" and drop rows in each group where 'X' is immediately followed by 'Y'? i.e. 'X' should be deleted in that case.

Required Output:

```
1     A        Y
2     A        X
3     A        Z
5     B        Y
7     B        Y
8     C        Y
10    C        Y
11    C        Y
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) for shifting per groups and compare by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) for `!=`, chain with bitwise `OR` - `|` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df.groupby('name')['nickname'].shift(-1).ne('Y') | df['nickname'].ne('X')

df = df[m]
print (df)
   name nickname
1     A        Y
2     A        X
3     A        Z
5     B        Y
7     B        Y
8     C        Y
10    C        Y
11    C        Y
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["A", "A","A", "A", "B" ,"B","B" ,"B", "C", "C","C", "C"],
                   "nickname":["X","Y","X","Z","X","Y","X","X","Y", "X","Y", "Y"]})

print (df)
   name nickname
0     A        X
1     A        Y
2     A        X
3     A        Z
4     B        X
5     B        Y
6     B        X
7     B        X
8     C        Y
9     C        X
10    C        Y
11    C        Y
```

---

```
m = df.groupby('name')['nickname'].shift(-1).ne('Y') | df['nickname'].ne('X')

df1 = df[m]
print (df1)
   name nickname
1     A        Y
2     A        X
3     A        Z
5     B        Y
6     B        X
7     B        X
8     C        Y
10    C        Y
11    C        Y

print(df[(df['nickname']!='X') | (df['nickname'].shift(-1)!='Y')])
   name nickname
1     A        Y
2     A        X
3     A        Z
5     B        Y
6     B        X
8     C        Y
10    C        Y
11    C        Y
```

Comment: Hi, If I want to include 'Z' also with 'Y' i.e. when 'X' is followed by 'Y' or 'Z' then remove 'X'...how can i do this?

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik - Sorry, but another answer is wrong, why accepting ?

Comment: ohh is it. It worked in the given data frame so I accepted it. How to do in this case can you please tell me when both 'Y' or 'Z' should be considered to remove 'X'

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik - sorry, but in your question is mentioned need `grouping`. So my answer do it. So why is accepting another answer with no group? I edit my answer what is difference - if last value of group is `X` and first value next grouop is `Y`, then another answer remove row, which cannot be removed, if need `groupby`

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik - and for your next question I think need `m = ~df.groupby('name')['nickname'].shift(-1).isin(['Y','Z']) | df['nickname'].ne('X')`

Comment: I think output of both of you guys code is giving the same output as required. I will go with your answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use `df[...]` for this, filter out the ones that are not needed, grouping is not really needed:

```
print(df[(df['nickname']!='X') | (df['nickname'].shift(-1)!='Y')])
```

Output:

```
   name nickname
1     A        Y
2     A        X
3     A        Z
5     B        Y
7     B        Y
8     C        Y
10    C        Y
11    C        Y
```

Update:

```
print(df[(df['nickname']!='X') | (df['nickname'].shift(-1).isin(['Y','Z'])==0)])
```

Comment: Hi, If I want to include 'Z' also with 'Y' i.e. when 'X' is followed by 'Y' or 'Z' then remove 'X'...how can i do this?

Comment: @AnkitaPatnaik Now?